# Parsing HTML With Complex Structure Using Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

Sorry for the noob html scraping question but I'm dealing with complex html and every situation is unique.

I'm trying to parse out all URLs that are preceeded by: {"actionType":"navigate","actionUrl":

In the example below it would be https://www.ABCD.com

I'm using python. Preferably beautiful soup. Thoughts on how to approach?

```
</a>
<a aria-label="ABCD." class="we-lockup targeted-link l-column small-2 medium-3 large-2 we-lockup--shelf-align-top ember-view" data-metrics-click='{"actionType":"navigate","actionUrl":"https://www.ABCD.com","targetType":"card","targetId":"12345"}' data-metrics-location='{"locationType":"shelfCustomersAlsoBoughtMovie"}' href="https://www.ABCD.com" id="ember123"> <picture class="we-lockup__artwork we-artwork--lockup we-artwork--fullwidth we-artwork--vhs-movie-pic we-artwork ember-view" dir="ltr" id="ember123">
<noscript>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the data to a Python dictionary (`dict`) using the built-in `json` module, and than access the `actionUrl` key.

```
import json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

data = soup.find(
    class_=
    'we-lockup targeted-link l-column small-2 medium-3 large-2 we-lockup--shelf-align-top ember-view'
)['data-metrics-click']

json_data = json.loads(data)

print(type(json_data))
print(json_data['actionUrl'])
```

Output:

```
<class 'dict'>
https://www.ABCD.com
```